# Faking HTTP Get request to download image

Tags: http, request

Trying to get image from this site http://traffic.ottawa.ca/map/camera?id=95. But no matter how I try it, always get Access Denied Image instead of a real one

Here is what I tried:

```
import shutil
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()

header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome)}
url = "http://traffic.ottawa.ca/map/camera?id=95"
response = requests.get(url, headers=header, stream=True)

with open('img1.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```

Also attempted using Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'http://traffic.ottawa.ca/map/camera?id=95'

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
desired_capabilities['chrome.page.customHeaders.User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
driver.get(url)
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

actionChains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('S').key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
actionChains.perform()
```

What is the proper way to fake a request, I thought it was all about the user agent, but apparently its not?

Comment: I get access denied by clicking your link. Looks like a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be blocked via cookie which is set by the website. The following works (or maybe not whenever you click it):

```
curl -v --cookie "JSESSIONID=0416883CFBE4DAB71539DCCCA05C584D" http://traffic.ottawa.ca/map/camera\?id\=2025 -o image
```

You can view the value of JSESSIONID from your dev tools. Now that you know the issue is, you can use your solution of choice to retrieve a valid cookie using your library of choice.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by **Slava Knyazev**, adding a cookie, solved the problem. Here is the final code

```
import shutil
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()

header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome)}
url = "http://traffic.ottawa.ca/map/camera?id=95"
cookie = {'JSESSIONID': '0416883CFBE4DAB71539DCCCA05C584D'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header, stream=True, cookies=cookie)

with open('img1.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```